# Is it possisble to avoid using converter in multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I came across a situation where I want to avoid using converter in multibinding, below is the xaml source snippet from my current code. **Below code works perfectly fine, but IS IT POSSIBLE to avoid converter first place ??**

**ViewModel:**

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    Cars = new List<string>() { "Audi", "BMW", "Ferrari", "Ford" };
    Models = new List<string>() { "Model 1", "Model 2" };
    IsOptionEnable = false;
}

public bool IsOptionEnable { get; private set; }
public List<string> Models { get; private set; }

public List<string> Cars { get; private set; }
```

**Main window xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="87.2,44.8,0,0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItm}"
              Style="{StaticResource ModelsComboBox}">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**Resource dictionary:**

```
<Style x:Key="ModelsComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ModelToBoolConverter}">
                            <Binding/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.IsOptionEnable" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Multivalue converter:**

```
internal sealed class ModelToBoolConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool enable = true;
        if ((values[0] != null && values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) &&
            (values[1] != null && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
        {
            var comboboxItemText = values[0] as string;
            if ((comboboxItemText == "Ferrari") && (bool)values[1] == false)
            {
                enable = false;
            }
        }

        return enable;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **MultiDataTrigger** to achieve the same.

**Resource dictionary:**

```
  <Style x:Key="ModelsComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding}" Value="Ferrari"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsOptionEnable,
                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}"
                                               Value="False"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: How it's different from already posted answer? (that too 6 mins before your answer)

Comment: @RohitVats This just happens sometimes when SO doesn't notify about new answers that were just posted. It happened to me right now.

Comment: @Clemens - Agree but after posting, you was able to see another answer and you delete it immediately. Happens with me as well (you can see my deleted answer). If this answer would have added any value to posted answer then i see no issue in posting improved answers.

Comment: @RohitVats: You are right, this answer is not much different from the another answer posted here, expect that the resource defined in another answer is anonymous resource (this style will applied to all the Combobox controls automatically) and this one you need to apply explicitly.

Comment: That's make no sense in relation to this answer. Inner content is what OP interested in.

Comment: @RohitVats: Well,It could be your personal view, which is certainly different from reality.

Comment: Oh really. Tell me one thing - OP already have x:Key associated with it. Do you think if you won't have specified it, OP would have remove it from his/her Style. You gotta be kidding dude..!!

Comment: @RohitVats: Well, i think we both are just wasting time by discussing unwanted things. i really don't understand what is bothering you a lot here. I assume this answer better fill the need.

Comment: I think @Ramashankar's answer is useful because it shows that Setters do not need to be defined between the `<MultiDataTrigger.Setters>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MultiDataTrigger` in this case.

```
           <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding}" Value="Ferrai"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsOptionEnable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```